# FullCalendar.js - Events avoiding current week?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I am currently using fullcalendar.js for a project (project is behind account wall hence screenshot) - and having fun with this plugin, all except the events I add to the calendar simply seem to avoid the current week? Image below of what is supposed to be an event from Nov 9th - 12th.

[blue event is in question, green event is working as intended (i believe due to not clashing with current week)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBytd.png)

No matter what dates I select, any outside of the current week will show correctly (i.e. ending on Nov 12th). If I set the start and end date to another week - it shows correctly, if the start date is before the current week and the end is not, the start date would show as intended by the end week would be pushed to the next week down.

Anybody have any idea or suggestions? I can't find anybody else having this problem on google seemingly.

Edit: apologies, forgot the javascript code calling the events:

```
                {
                id: 2,
                title: '',
                start: new Date(2018,10,9),
                end: new Date(2018,10,12),
                url: '#',
                className: 'calendar-Pending staff_holiday'
            },
            {


                id: 1,
                title: '',
                start: new Date(2018,10,14),
                end: new Date(2018,10,16),
                url: '#',
                className: 'calendar-Approved staff_holiday'
            }
```

Any other code required let me know

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/12/ - your event data looks fine to me, although the dates you've shown in the code appear not to be the same as the dates used in your screenshot. I've added an extra one to cover all the scenarios you mention. Unfortunately you didn't show the rest of your calendar config or your CSS, but I would guess somewhere you've got some code or CSS which is causing these events not to appear somehow. It's hard to say what, but custom CSS can often be a problem. Start by removing that and using the default fullCalendar CSS instead, and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Annoyingly, the following day(Nov 6th) - the issue had cleared and all dates show correctly. So I may have to wait to find out the actual issue - it could be the first day of the week or something similiar. I will keep an eye out and report back if it appears again, thank you though!

Comment: you could always experiment adding different events until you see it again. But maybe it was some temporary glitch if you were in the middle of making changed during development. By all means if it happens again, edit the question with the new information though and tag me in a comment  (use @ followed by my username) to bring it to my attention. Thanks.